# How do I prove this fattened set is connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a normed space and $G$ be open in $X$.

Let $\alpha:I\rightarrow G$ be a path. ($I:=[0,1]$)

Then, does there exist a connected open subset $E$ such that $\alpha(I)\subset E \subset G$?

Since $I$ is compact, $\alpha(I)$ is compact. Hence, there are finite $\epsilon$-balls covering $\alpha(I)$ each of which is contained in $G$. Since $\alpha(I)$ is connected, the union of these $\epsilon$-balls must be connected. (We can show this by adding another ball to one ball, and continuing this process) Hence the proof is done.

However, I wonder if there is a much better one rather than the finite union of balls.

That is, since $\alpha(I)$ is compact, there is an $\epsilon$-fattening of this image contained in $G$.

That is, $\{x\in X: d(x,\alpha(I)) <\epsilon\}\subset G$.

I think the set $\{x\in X: d(x,\alpha(I)) <\epsilon\}$ is indeed connected, but cannot figure out what to do. How do I prove it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can show that it's path-connected.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I think the problem is finding an $\epsilon$ that makes it a subset of $G$.

Comment: @RobArthan I think the OP has that part, "That is, since $\alpha(I)$ is compact, …", and the connectedness is the problem.

Comment: @DanielFischer: maybe you're right. I've deleted my answer for the time being and will leave it to Rubertos to clarify the question.

Comment: I am asking how to show the fattend set is connected.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh right.. So when $x$ is in the fattend set, is it done by constructing straight paths starting from $x$ to a point in $\alpha(I)$?

Comment: Right. A straight line segment to reach $\alpha(I)$, a part on the curve $\alpha(I)$, then a straight line segment to the target. [Where the straight line segments may be degenerate.]